# Copying malformed gzipped S3 object to RDS or efficiently changing line terminator

Tags: python, postgresql, boto3, amazon-rds, gzip

I have an S3 object from a third-party data provider who has (by whatever mechanism) inconsistently written this object.  The header row is terminated by a newline `\n` but every subsequent row is terminated by a carriage return+line feed `\r\n`.  This object is gzipped csv.  I want to copy this to our S3 bucket from theirs, and then copy that object into a PostgreSQL RDS table using the [`aws_s3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html) extensions.  These extensions can usually handle gzipped csv files, but because the header row has a different line terminator than the remaining rows, a copy fails with the following error even with copy options `'(format csv, delimiter '','', header true)'`:

```
psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: unquoted carriage return found in data
HINT:  Use quoted CSV field to represent carriage return.
```

Ultimately, I gather from the PostgreSQL source code that this is because of the inconsistency in line terminators; the PostgreSQL engine looks to the first row to determine line terminator even with `header true`.

So my first question is, is my assessment here true, or is there a way to instruct PostgreSQL COPY to handle a csv file where the header has a newline character at the end but a carriage return ending all other lines?

Assuming that it cannot, I now need to normalize the line terminator before I write this object out to S3.  From `boto3`'s `get_object` I have a bunch of bytes:

```
resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="the-source-bucket", Key="location/of/the_object.csv.gz")
body_bytes = resp["Body"].read()
```

And I want to replace any instance of `\r\n` with just `\n` before I do something like

```
s3_client.put_object(
  Bucket="the-destination-bucket", 
  Key="/location/of/the/output.csv[.gz?]", 
  Body=<body_bytes with the correct line terminator everywhere>
)
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I don't know all the details of your situation, but I would cheat by using Athena.  I would load the file as a single-column table using the `string` type and `\n` as the row delimiter.  I am pretty sure the `\r` characters will not be a problem.  I would CTAS the entire table into a new gzip file on S3, wrapping the one column with a `replace(mycolumn, chr(13),'')`.

Comment: @MikeOrganek That's a fine idea!  And probably something I'd do in another case.  But for my particular situation, I'd really like to avoid bringing in another AWS service and adding another stage in the ETL.  It's certainly far from ideal (I'd prefer if this vendor didn't do stupid things), but I think my best hope is some manipulation of the `resp["Body"]` stream in-flight to normalize line terminators.  For other reasons particular to my situation, I'd also like to avoid writing this normalized result to a file before `put_object` is called.

Comment: Your assessment is correct. I don't know the most efficient way to correct it, but I think changing the first row is safer than trying to change every row after the first.  If any of your data includes embedded newlines, changing them would be changing your data.

Comment: I'm not really arguing with your reasons here since they are perfectly valid, but I want to point out that your solution rewrites the file and is another step in your ETL.  The fact that you will need to gunzip (which can be done on-the-fly) before fixing the linends and then gzip is why I suggested Athena.  I also agree with the suggestion from @jjanes

Comment: @MikeOrganek This vendor does things in a really stupid way, honestly.  I have to assume a role in their account to do a GetObject, but because roles in our account don't have usage of their KMS key (and they are apparently unable to grant this permission), I have to use their role to GetObject, keep this object in memory, switch roles to one of mine, and then PutObject with that.  So that's why I preferred an approach where I simply modify the object while I'm already holding onto it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, RDS is not able to deal with inconsistent line terminators, so I do have to normalize them beforehand.  Something like this is what I ended up doing:

```py
resp = s3_client.get_object(
  Bucket="the-source-bucket",
  Key="location/of/the_object.csv.gz")
)
body = resp["Body"].read()

# This line splits on any line terminator,
# whether or not it is consistent between lines
lines = gzip.decompress(body).splitlines()

s3_client.put_object(
  ContentEncoding="gzip",
  # Now we write the object with a consistent line terminator
  Body=gzip.compress(b"\n".join(lines)),
  Bucket="the-destination-bucket",
  Key="location/of/the_object.csv.gz"
)
```

Comment: If the data is small enough to decompress in RAM, then you may want to simply write directly to the table using `copy_from()` or psycopg3's `copy` instead of rewriting to S3. https://www.psycopg.org/articles/2020/11/15/psycopg3-copy/